# How can I list files with their absolute path, group and user in linux?

Tags: linux, path, find, ls

I want to generate recursive file listings with their full information: absolute path, group, user, created time & etc.

But, if I use a `find` command like `find /`, I only get the relative path. I would like `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 669319168 Mar 11 17:10 /root/valhalla-i386-disc2.iso`

Comment: Whether or not you can get `creation time` depends on your file system. You can however get last modification time (what `ls` shows), access time, and status change time on most linux fs's.

Answer (score 0):

[find](/questions/tagged/find) has a specific action which essentially does what you want

```
-ls    True; list current file in ls -dils format on standard output.
```